# Character Controller speed: running vs. walking

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I imported the standard characters package into a fresh Unity project, and then dragged a 3rd person character controller prefab and dropped it into the scene.

However, I cannot seem to figure out which variable to modify to get the avatar to walk!

I keep changing the speed-related settings, but the character always seems to be running when I press the key `W`.

I would appreciate some help to get me started in this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created example code for you. You can see how It works and set its own. If you show your character controller codes I try to be more help.

There is two step;
1. Set your character animation controller like this.
[image: Animation Controller]

2. Call animation from your character controller script like this.

   ```
   using UnityEngine;
   using System.Collections;
   public class Test : MonoBehaviour 
   {
       private Animator anim;
       float yourSpeed;

       void Awake () 
       {
           anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
       }

       void Update () 
       {
           if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.W) && yourSpeed > 100f) 
           { //I dont know how works your speed.
           anim.SetTrigger ("RunAnim");
           } 
           else if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.W)) 
           {
           anim.SetTrigger ("WalkAnim");
           }
           else 
           {
           anim.SetTrigger("IdleAnim");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Also you can watch [official unity](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/animation/animator-scripting) tutorial.

Comment: Thank you very much Valar. I will study this and implement my own version, and let you know if I need further help. Cheers

Comment: Hi Valar, My character is controlled by the standard scripts that are attached to the 3rd person controller prefab. Does this mean I have to modify them, or create a new script and attach it to my character, or both?

Comment: You can modify animation codes in controller script.

Comment: Thanks Valar. I need more help, but I realized I could not fit my question for you in a comment, so I asked a new question, if you could please take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31564090/unity-5-1-animator-controller-not-transitioning