# Unity 5.1 Animator Controller not transitioning

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have created an `Animator Controller` (called `Player`) and assigned it to the `Animator` field of my humanoid avatar, as well as simple animation states with suitable transitions. Please see the two attached images.

I have attached a script, containing the following code, to my avatar game object, but I wonder what I am missing or doing wrong that the transition from `Idle` to `Walk` does not take place, even though I can see that the `speed` variable increases when I press `W`.

Could someone please help me understand the problem?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CharAnim : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator animator;
    float speed;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {    
      animator.SetFloat( "speed", Input.GetAxis("Vertical") );

      if ( Input.GetKeyDown( KeyCode.W ) && ( speed > 0.5f ) ) 
      {
          animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
      }
      else 
      {
          animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
      }
    }
}
```

x

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is, `animator.SetTrigger("Walk");` gets called in a single frame when you pressed the key and `animator.SetTrigger("Idle");` gets called for the rest of the frames.

Try changing `Input.GetKeyDown( KeyCode.W )` to  `Input.GetKey( KeyCode.W )`.  The former returns true only once, the instant when you press down the key, whereas the latter returns true until you release the key. Something like :

```
void Update ()
{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}
```

On a side note, you don't need the `speed` variable in the `Animator` to trigger walk animation, since you are already doing that using `W`.

[image: Animator setup]

Idle -> Walk
[image]

Walk -> Idle
[image]

Comment: Thanks Nimesh. I made the change you suggested, but the `Idle` state remains persistent. The speed goes up to `1` though the transition does not take place. Are you able to replicate this situation?

Comment: Yes, I tried the same here and it works. Are you sure you have set up the Animator properly?
Idle State -----------Walk------------> Walk State
Walk State ----------Idle-------------> Idle State
Don't use the speed variable if you are using the boolean to set the trigger.

Comment: Additionally, remove the AnyState & Entry from your Animator if your are not using them. I, personally, prefer to set up each state and their transitions manually.

Comment: It all starts fine, and I keep running and testing it, but as soon as I press `Maximize on Play` then it stops working... The animations stop showing progress bar, the transitions don't happen, the arrows don't increase or decrease, etc...

Comment: are you saying that the transitions work fine if you don't maximize on play?

Comment: Absolutely...  I submitted a bug report.  Please try that when you have time and see if you can replicate the scenario.  Here is my bug report description:

Comment: _I start off creating an empty Animator Controller, opening its tab, making the simplest one-state Idle animation, and defining vSpeed and hSpeed to use with arrow keys. Not even a transition - just this basic scenario. I check over and over again to make sure when I press play, the state animation progress bar shows that it runs. I, also, check the arrow keys to see if the speed variables go up and down. It all works fine, repeatedly, until I click "Maximize on Play" and then it all stops working: the animation state does not show the progress bar, the arrow keys do not register, etc..._

Comment: I tried the same thing after I saw your comment, but it works fine for me. Beats me.

Answer (score -2):

```html
{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
    }
    else            
        animator.SetTrigger("Idle");
}{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Walk");
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/25365897)